# DirectX 11 texture filter linear/point flicker

Tags: textures, directx-11, sampling, flicker

I wrote a small **DirectX 11** application on **Windows 10 x64** using **C++**.
Now I want to render some low resolution textures (e.g. 16px * 16px) without loosing it's sharpness on magnifications *(how in games like Terraria)*.
So the only options I see are making the sprite textures high resolution or change the sampler state from **D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR** to **D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT**.
The former is not an option for me because I want to save video memory and not wasting it for redundant information.
But the second approach cause some new problem.
If I move a textured rectangle using this sampler I get an annoying flicker.

**Point:**
[image]

**Linear:**
[image]

**Point:**
[image]

**Linear:**
[image]

After thinking about it I came to the result that using **D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT** will always cause this flicker.
The following image illustrates how I understood point filtering and also shows the reason for flicker.
On it one can see an horizontal sampling process, using point filtering, from an low resolution textured rectangle moving to the right.

[image]

I did not post any code because I think this issue is not related to any specific code and would not help at all.
So if I am wrong with this assumption please tell.
**Finally the question is how I can fix this or what alternatives are left?**

Comment: The answer is in your question, you need to align the textured quad texels with the surface pixels. To ensure that, you need to only shift your quad/uv by a multiple of the texel ratio. You can achieve what you desire either with a linear or nearest sampler, but if possible, try to keep the linear one, as it may be faster than nearest on modern hardware.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The filtering mode doesn't have anything to do with memory usage. You can use these filtering modes even on textures without mipmap chains, although the filtering is less effective when the target pixel size would use a lower mip.

Nearest-point filtering is likely to always cause artifacts unless you can ensure exactly a 1:1 texel-to-pixel mapping, so it's not particularly useful.

`SpriteBatch` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) defaults to using `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR` and `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR` which tends to work best for 2D sprites.

You could try using `D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC` to see if that improves your scenario, but keep in mind that you have to use a `MaxAnisotropy` of 2 if you are supporting [Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 9.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/). If you have any higher feature level, you can use `D3D11_MAX_MAXANISOTROPY`.

> For modern PCs or the Universal Windows Platform (UWP), a minimum of `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3` is reasonable as 9.2 and 9.1 are quite old. Even Windows phone is at least 9.3.

Comment: "The filtering mode doesn't have anything to do with memory usage.". I think you misunderstood me. I did not mean that the filtering mode is causing more or less memory consumption. I meant that if I am using linear filtering I have to use much bigger textures, which causes more memory consumption. So I am wondering whether there is an better way.

Comment: Why does linear vs. point make any difference in the texture size at all?

Comment: For example if I stretch a 16px x 16px texture to 200px x 200px it will look blurry with linear and sharp with point filtering. So the only way it will look sharp in linear is to increase the texture size.

Comment: So your basic problem is that you have super-small artwork rendering to a small screen that you want to blow-up for modern, large monitors. You'd rather have a blocky result than a blurry result. You need to be very careful to move all your artwork by exact pixel increments then if you want to avoid the aliasing effects.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

There is a filtering technique called [bilateral filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter), where the idea is to blur more where local contrast is low, and blur less where local contrast is high, to preserve edges. It might be possible to (manually) upsample your low resolution texture using a similar idea...

If your texture is such that a low-resolution version looks good enough, then higher resolution plus **texture compression** might work for you.

There is also **multisampling** (MSAA). Perhaps point sampling works acceptable with multisampling enabled. Note that you will probably need to also do/enable multisample *shading*, because if not, all samples for a pixel would have the same color.